# ScrollView positions being restarted on a child component re-render (update)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, scrollview

I am having an issue (this is probably something I am ignoring within the render cycle) maintaining the position of two different scroll views when some of its child components are updated.

I have a hierarchy of views that is like:

```
<ScrollView vertical scrolling ability>
    ...
    <ScrollView horizontal and vertical scrolling ability>
    ...
        <Matrix>
            <Cell updateCellStatusHandler={handler}>
        </Matrix>
    ...
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

So, the updates on the internal cells, are resetting both scrolls on cell status update and this generates a super weird experience with the user having to scroll down/left/right back to continue interacting with the Matrix of cells with a status I have.

I have tried to save the scrollOffset (x,y) using `useState` but if I change some cell, the state is reseted to (0,0) which is my initial state.

```
const [scrollOffset, setScrollOffset] = useState({
    scrollX: 0,
    scrollY: 0,
})
```

But without luck.

```
<ScrollView
      {...props}
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
      ref={scrollReference}
      // tslint:disable-next-line: jsx-no-lambda
      onScroll={event => {
        setScrollOffset({
          scrollX: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x,
          scrollY: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y,
        })
      }}
      onScrollEndDrag={event => {
        console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
        console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x)
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
</ScrollView>
```

One possible approach to solve this is to have a mechanism that allow me to save the scroll position before the update. But this will complicate a lot the communication between components, etc. 
By the way, the cell status update is being handled via Redux.

If some of you can bring you some light over this, would be great.

---- UPDATE 1 (Code of the panel component added) ----

Parent component is:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomScrollView enableResetScrollToCoords={false}>
        <Section>
          <WhiteContainer>
            <View style={styles.rateContainer}>
              <DescriptionTextStatus
                statusText={getMessageForRate(availabilityRate)}
                descriptionText={getDescriptionForRate(
                  availabilityRate,
                  isTeacher,
                )}
                icon={getImageForRate(availabilityRate)}
              />
            </View>
          </WhiteContainer>
        </Section>
        {!loggedUserIsTeacher() && <AvailabilityStart />}
        <AvailabilityPanel />
        <AvailabilityStatus />
        <AvailabilityButtonSave />
      </CustomScrollView>
    </View>
```

Availability Panel is one of the childs

```
export const AvailabilityPanel: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  const panel: Cell[][] = useSelector((state: ReduxStore) => {
    return get(state.entities, 'availability.panel', undefined)
  })

  if (panel === undefined) {
    return <Nothing />
  }

  return (
    <Section>
      <WhiteContainer>
        <LinearGradient
          start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
          end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
          colors={[Palette.White, Palette.White68]}
        >
          <View style={styles.rateContainer}>
            <DescriptionTextStatus
              statusText={strings.warning}
              descriptionText={strings.selectionMessage}
              icon={'clock'}
            />
            <View style={styles.separator} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView
              style={styles.scrollView}
              directionalLockEnabled={false}
              horizontal={true}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            >
              <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                <View style={styles.weekdaysContainer}>
                  <PanelHeader weekdays={weekdays} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.rowsContainer}>
                  {hours.map((hourLabel: string, index: number) => {
                    return (
                      <PanelRow
                        key={index}
                        hourLabel={hourLabel}
                        hoursRow={panel[index]}
                        rowIndex={index}
                      />
                    )
                  })}
                </View>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </LinearGradient>
      </WhiteContainer>
    </Section>
  )
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give me snack demo so i can fix your problem?

Comment: I have edited the post @MuhammadNuman

Comment: ***I have tried to save the scrollOffset (x,y) using useState but if I change some cell, the state is reseted to (0,0) which is my initial state.*** Which component were you storing the state in. Please add the code of this component which your used state in and the parent of it. Its clear that the issue here is that your component is getting unmounted and mounted again, instead of re-rendered when you update value in a cell

Answer (score 4):

ScrollView does not reset scroll position because of child updates, regardless of whether you use Redux or not. You don't need to try to patch it with workarounds like saving current scroll positions. Rather just figure out what's wrong with your setup

It's hard to tell because you didn't provide your actual code, but I'm pretty sure one or both ScrollViews are remounted on updates (old ScrollView is removed and new one is created in its place with its own scroll position). It's likely that you are declaring new components inside render function so React will just remount them every time

Comment: I have added the code. Thanks for your ideas. I am looking forward to your additional thoughts after you take a look.

Comment: I can't see any obvious problems with provided code, but then again, there is a lot of custom components involved. Start with one of the inner components, drop some console.logs in `componentDidMount` (or its analogy with `useEffect`) to find out if they are remounting. If they do, keep going up until you find the problem @halbano

Comment: Sorry, but what do you exactly mean with re-mounting? Or better, where in the React lifecycle or in which conditions a child component would be re-mounted?

Comment: remounting is when instead of updating component (making it re-render) you (mostly inadvertently) cause it to be unmounted and re-created again. That is, one instance of component unmounts and another instance of it mounts in its place on every render. There can be a number of reasons for this, one of which, the most probable one, I've mentioned in my answer

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful comment. I tried a bunch of stuff like trying to save the content offset to reset scroll to the previous position but to every time even that kept re-mounting the ScrollView and resetting scroll. All I had to do was pull the content out to its own scope (outside of the component it was in) and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think the overall idea of saving the scroll position of your scrollview is good.

I think the fact that your state is reset to 0 is probably due to Redux (not sure however, could you precise how your component is connected to redux ?). I am not so familiar with Hooks, but in a React Class component, I would try to save the scroll position in a non state property of the class. Maybe save it in a variable outside of your functional component ?

Then in the handler to manage cell updates, you could ensure that your scrollview scrolls to the position you saved (using [ScrollView.scrollTo()](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto), with `{animated: false}` option so that the animation is not visible for the user)

Comment: Hey @romchambe, the component is connected to redux using the useSelector hook from react-redux. Anyway, you are right in the fact that the component is connected to the store and something (in this case the panel) changed in there. 

From your suggestion, an idea could be to save the position on the store also. I thought anyway that a component should be able to handle its own state (that is set properly the "previous" scroll offset when re-initialized) without any extra dependency. What do you think?

Comment: Could you share your whole component and maybe the reducer in the question ? Otherwise I think it might be a bit hard to answer precisely. 

You are right about the component handling its own state, and it is also true for the scrollview : usually, the scroll position should not be reset to 0 if the parent updates, unless you control the scroll position in the parent. here you store the position in the parent, but you do not "control" it (you would do that with ScrollView.scrollTo() method)

Comment: I have added the code. Thanks for your ideas. I am looking forward to your additional thoughts after you take a look.